# Python Edward No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'

Tags: python, tensorflow, edward

I am trying to use the Edward library. However, it seems that Edward is having some issues finding tensorflow.contrib.

Has anybody any idea how to solve this?

I tried uninstalling tensorflow 2.14 and installing the old version 1.14 but it still does not work.

I read that I have to find contrib in some other package.

Many thanks!!